# http headers in flask not working on linux server

Tags: python-2.7, flask, http-headers

I am using Flask to generate REST API.

I want to check authorization header which is sent by mobile apps.

I am using below code

```
from flask import request
cookie_data = request.headers.get('auth_token')
```

It is working on local machine, but when i host it on server it is not working, when i debug it gives null value.
The difference is, on my local machine **flask version = 0.10.1**  **python =2.7.8**
on server **flask = 0.10.1**, **python= 2.6.9**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that only alphanumeric characters or '-' are allowed.

Any headers not conforming these will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the Python version is the issue; it probably has something to do with server configuration.  Specifically, "auth_token" is not a standard HTTP header, so your server may be filtering it out from the request before it gets to Flask.

You may want to test with one of the [standard headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), such as "Authorization".  If this works, then it's likely that the problem is the nonstandard header.

Comment: if i want more custom header, how do i add

Comment: really thanks for your answer, it save my time. i just figure out how only alphanumeric characters or '-' are allowed.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This answer helped me after a whole day of hair pulling frustration, just because one of my HTTP Headers was `user_id` :)